# Mongodb equivalent of SQL subquery

Tags: subquery, spring-data-mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB and want an equivalent of an sql subquery as listed below

```
select * from records where status = "OFF" and category not in (select category from records where status = "ON");
```

As of now, I am using 2 different find() in SpringDataMongo as follows

```
List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("status").is("ON"));
List<MyDocument> documents = (List<MyDocument>) mongoTemplate.find(query, MyDocument.class);
for(MyDocument doc : documents ) {
   categories.add(doc.getCategory());
}
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("category").nin(categories));
documents = (List<MyDocument>) mongoTemplate.find(query, MyDocument.class);
```

Can I do it one aggregate ?

Comment: please share your document structure of MongoDB.